# Sitecore download media folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I have a requirement to remove several PDFs from specific folder our Sitecore media library, possibly over 1000 documents.  We need to maintain the file names of these PDFs and would prefer to maintain the "file structure/hierarchy" of these documents.

We have tried using the Sitecore Powershell Extensions "Download" feature, but it does not appear to download the PDFs, only the content items themselves.  We can create a package, but the folder that contains the resulting PDFs have had their file names replaced with GUIDs.

Is there a PS script available or any other way to do a bulk download of these media library PDFs?

P.S.  I am a Powershell neophyte, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use the [`Send-File`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Send-File.html%20%22Send%20File%22) command. When executed on a media library item, it allows you to download the associated blob stored in that item.

Example:

```
PS master:\>Get-Item "master:\media library\files\pdfs\mypdffile" | Send-File -Message "PDF Download"
```

You can pass `-NoDialog` to it so the user is not propmted each time.

So for multiple files you can do:

```
Get-Item -Path master -Query "/sitecore/#media library#/files//*[@@templatename='Pdf']" | 
    Send-File -NoDialog
```

I can't see performance being great with 1000's of files for that tho. Also it will not keep the path, all files will be saved directly to your `Downloads` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may be interested in using the download capability through SPE Remoting. This is an alternative solution that operates outside of Sitecore and connects through the web service.

Sample script for downloading:

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Modules/Remoting%20Tests%20-%20Download%20with%20RemoteScriptCall.ps1

Book details on getting setup:

https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/remoting.html